# How to avoid specifying field name in Octokit GraphQL

Tags: graphql, octokit-js

Example query:

```
mutation prrt($input: AddPullRequestReviewThreadInput!) {
    addPullRequestReviewThread(input: $input) {
        thread {
            id
        } } }
```

Using Octokit, I have to type like this:

```js
const mutateFn = graphql<{
    addPullRequestReviewThread: AddPullRequestReviewThreadPayload;
}>;
const response = await mutateFn(mutation, { input, headers });
```

The `addPullRequestReviewThread:`  part is quite long. Can this be automated/inferred somehow? I'd like to just specify the payload type `AddPullRequestReviewThreadPayload`. Or is this required in all GraphQL?